# putting an input field inside a table row

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is a trivial question but how can I place a checkbox inside a table row that is being echoed inside php script. Currently I'm getting an error with what I have

here is the code

```
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Coalition</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Select</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['coalition'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type="checkbox" name ="selected[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\Voting\includes\list.inc.php on line 45 (this line is the checkbox)

Comment: *"Currently I'm getting an error with what I have"* - Being what? which you *failed* to provide. Edit: ah, there it is now https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45195955/2. Escape your double quotes inside the echo.

Comment: Have a close look at your quotes `"`

Comment: oh... a parse error! Of course

Comment: [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them) a dupe of.

Comment: try this echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name =\"selected[]\" value=\"echo $row[id]\"/></td>";

Comment: @Tim thanks for the answer but it does not work. I get this error  Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\Voting\includes\list.inc.php on line 45

Comment: Whoops. take out the echo in the value attribute.

Comment: @Tim I changed it to this: "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name =\"selected[]\" value=\"echo $row['id']\"/></td>"; and I still get this error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Comment: @Tim in $row[ 'id' ] if I remove the ' ' it does not give the error but id becomes unidentified

Comment: take out the "echo" and the single quote around $row['id']. It should read value=\" $row[id]\ ". Is id the actual column name? And is id in your query?

Comment: @Tim yes that is the column name in the DB. I did what you said above and id is unidentified

Comment: Whats your SQL statement?

Comment: @Tim my bad about the last comment. The id was different in DB, still the checkbox does not appear in front of the rows

Comment: You should have something like this: echo " <td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"selected[]\" value=\"$row[someColumnName]\"  /></td>";  Thats always worked for me. Replace someColumnName with the actual column in the DB.

Comment: @Tim You said to remove it. that's it! thank you very much

Comment: I meant inside the value attribute..... Its not a problem....